# Determine limit of $W_0(a_n b_n \text{exp}(b_n +c)) - (b_n+c)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, lambert-w

Suppose we have some sequences of positive real numbers $a_n$, $b_n$, with $a_n \to a \in \mathbb{R}$, $b_n \to \infty$.

Furthermore, suppose some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

How could I determine the limit (if it exists) of 
$$ W_0 (a_n b_n \text{exp}(b_n +c)) - (b_n +c)$$,

where $W_0(x)$ is Lambert's W, defined as the real inverse of $f(x) =  x  \text{exp}(x)$.

I do not know which technique one could apply here.  I tried to use some of the identities that one can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but did not find anything to useful.

For example, using $ \ln W_0(x) = \ln x - W_0(x)$, one could rewrite this as

$$\ln  \frac{a_n b_n}{W_0 (a_n b_n \text{exp}(b_n +c))} $$

Any hints would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the wikipedia page of the Lambert W function, you can find the following useful approximation of $W_0$:
[$$W_0(x) = \ln(x) - \ln(\ln(x)) + o(1)$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions)
This means
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}W_0(x) - (\ln(x) - \ln(\ln(x))) = 0$$
Because the argument of $W_0$ in your expression tends to infinity, we can substitute the approximation without changing the limit.

We can then compute as follows (using $\ln(a_nb_ne^{b_n+c}) = \ln(a_nb_n)+b_n+c$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty} W_0 (a_n b_n e^{b_n +c}) - (b_n +c) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(a_nb_n) - \ln(\ln(a_nb_n)+b_n+c)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{a_nb_n}{\ln(a_nb_n)+b_n+c}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{a_n}{\frac{\ln(a_nb_n)}{b_n}+1+\frac{c}{b_n}}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(a_nb_n)}{b_n}+1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c}{b_n}}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{a}{0+1+0}\right)\\
&= \ln(a)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you, must have overlooked that part in the wikipedia article!